# The Regression model either overfits or underfits

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, regression

I have used ElasticNet as a prediction method. There are 265 predictors and 127 samples. I have used 5-fold non-nested cross validation to evaluate the performance of the model. I obtained both training and test R2 score percentages on the 5-folds to check if the model has high bias or high variance. There are 2 hyperparameters to tune: l1-ratio and alpha. Using the gridsearchCV (cv=5) gives an estimator which pretty much overfits (Train score=0.82, Test score=0.16 for alpha=2^-5). I increased the lower bound for alpha range gradually from 2^-10 to 2^1 to impose more regularization on the model, this although helps to reduce the variance of the model, cause the model to have high bias or low score (Train score=0.13, Test score=0.05 for alpha=2). 
How can I have a model which neither overfits or underfits, i.e. have relatively good test and train scores simultaneously?

Comment: You have twice as many predictors as data points? I would say if you can't collect more data, try reduce the number of predictors. Sure many of highly correlated? Try remove some of those. Otherwise maybe consider using PCA to reduce the dimensionality.

Comment: As @Dan said this situation is hopeless.  How would you expect to model 265 predictors when your sample size of 127 is just large enough to precisely estimate the effect of a single pre-specified predictor?  See [BBR](http://fharrell.com/links) Chapter 20